# ng-options with index includes a blank value by default

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm trying to use ng-options (with index as value) to create a dropdown with the first element selected by default. I tried setting the model in the controller but that does not help.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.model = 0;
    $scope.years = [2012, 2013, 2014];
}

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="model" ng-options="idx as year for (idx, year) in years"></select>
    <p ng-bind="model"></p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kxugpwxk/

What am I doing wrong? Why is there a blank value selected at the top of the dropdown?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/gkJve/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` in the ng-options call.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="model" ng-options="years.indexOf(year) as year for year in years"></select>
  <p ng-bind="model"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<select ng-options="idx as year for (idx, year) in years" ng-model="model"  ng-init="model = years[0]"></select>
```

Normally , this should solve your problem .